# Qt QML How to scroll back to ListView header?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5

If i select an item in my ListView with a header, i want the list scrolls up in a short animation to place the currently selected item on the top of the list and the header is moved up and not visible. That works with the following code. However when i want to scroll down to see the list header again, it always snaps back to the top (first) item of the list. That is most likely caused by `highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange`. But how i can avoid this?

I tried `highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange` which let me scroll to the header again, but that causes the items are often not moved to the top which is not acceptable.
I tried `headerPositioning: ListView.PullBackHeader` but that gives me the same results like `headerPositioning: ListView.PullBackHeader`

```
ListView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true
    spacing: 11
    focus: true
    highlightMoveDuration: 400
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0
    preferredHighlightEnd: 100
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange

    headerPositioning: ListView.InlineHeader
    header: Rectangle {
                id: headerBar
                height: 116
                color: "blue"
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left
                    right: parent.right
                    leftMargin: 12
                    rightMargin: 12
                }
            }

    model: myModel

    delegate: ListItem {
                  height: 56
                  width: list.width
                  color: "red"
                  onListItemClicked: {
                      list.currentIndex = index
                  }
              }
}
```

I expect the selected items in the ListView always scroll to the top of the list (inside the `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHighlightEnd`) and that i can scroll manually down to see the ListView header. Does anyone know a solution?

I dont see a solution in [How can I animate scrolling in a QML ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682077/how-to-animate-scroll-in-a-qml-scrollview) since i don't want to use a scroll bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate scroll in a QML ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682077/how-to-animate-scroll-in-a-qml-scrollview)

Comment: Its not a duplicate since i can not use a scrollbar as proposed in the solution of the mentioned duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the strict range only on click and remove it after to allow smooth mouse scroll:

```
ListView {
    // ....
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.NoHighlightRange

    delegate: ListItem {
        // ...
        onListItemClicked: {
            list.highlightRangeMode = ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
            list.currentIndex = index
            list.highlightRangeMode = ListView.ApplyRange
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reset to `list.highlightRangeMode = ListView.ApplyRange` just after setting the index did not work, the items did not scroll to the top. Given that idea i tried then `onMovementStarted: item_list.highlightRangeMode = ListView.ApplyRange`, so the `highlightRangeMode` is just set back to `ListView.ApplyRange` after the first scroll started and that worked fine then. Thanks for the hint.